# How to use extract the hidden layer features in H2ODeepLearningEstimator?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, h2o

I found H2O has the function h2o.deepfeatures in R to pull the hidden layer features
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.20.0.8/topics/h2o.deepfeatures

```
train_features <- h2o.deepfeatures(model_nn, train, layer=3)
```

But I didn't find any example in Python? Can anyone provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Python/R API functions are wrappers around REST calls. See http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/_modules/h2o/model/model_base.html#ModelBase.deepfeatures

So, to convert an R example to a Python one, move the model to be the `this`, and all other args should shuffle along. I.e. the example from the manual becomes (with dots in variable names changed to underlines):

```
prostate_hex = ...
prostate_dl = ...
prostate_deepfeatures_layer1 = prostate_dl.deepfeatures(prostate_hex, 1)
prostate_deepfeatures_layer2 = prostate_dl.deepfeatures(prostate_hex, 2)
```

Sometimes the function name will change slightly (e.g. `h2o.importFile()` vs. `h2o.import_file()` so you need to hunt for it at http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/index.html